# Looping over files in a folder for shell script with multiple inputs

Tags: bash, loops, command-line, multiple-arguments

**Specifying multiple inputs for command line tool?**

I am new to bash and am wanting to loop a command line program over a folder containing numerous files.

The script takes two input files (in my case, these differ in one field of the file name ("...*R1*" vs "...*R2*"). Running a single instance of the tool looks like this:

```
tool_name infile1 infile2 -o outfile_suffix
```

Actual example:

```
casper sample_name_R1_001.out.fastq sample_name_R2_001.out.fastq -o sample_name_merged
```

**File name format:**

> DCP-137-**5102**-T1A3_S33_L001_R1_001.fastq
>   DCP-137-**5102**-T1A3_S33_L001_R2_001.fastq

The field in bold will vary between different pairs (e.g., 2000, 2110, 5100 etc...) with each pair distinguished by either R1 or R2.

I would like to know how to loop the script over a folder containing numerous pairs of matched files, and also ensure that the output (-o) gets the 'sample_name' suffix.

I am familiar with the basic `for file in ./*.*; do ... $file...; done` but that obviously won't work for this example. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Does every pair contain R1 and R2? Can you give some more examples of the filename pairs?

Comment: Yes, one member of the pair will have R1 and the other will have R2. I have updated the post with a more detailed description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to loop over the `R1`'s and derive the `R2` and merged-file names from that, something like:

```
for file1 in ./*R1*; do
    file2=${file1/R1/R2}
    merge=${file1#*R1}_merged
    casper ${file1} ${file2} -o ${merge}
done
```

Note: Markdown is showing the `#*R1}_merged` as a comment -- it's not

Comment: Thanks! This was a great help.  Side note:  "${file1#*R1}_merge" removes the characters preceding "R1" from the file path (including the sample name), rather than the tailing characters. But using "${file1/R1*/_}merged" solved that issue.

Comment: @ColinAnthony No problem.  Yes, that should have been `${file1%R1*}merged` but glad you resolved it.